# "Invert" a JavaScript object hash whose values are arrays to produce a new object hash with keys as the elements of those original value vectors

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, hash-map, underscore.js, lodash.js

## Background

[lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#invert) and [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#invert) have an `invert` function that takes an object hash and converts it to a new one, which has keys as the input object's values and values as the input object's keys. As such, if the values in the input object aren't unique, this non-unique input value will, when it's a key in the output object, have as its value only one of the input object's keys.

An example:

```
_.invert({a: 1, b: 2, c: 2})
// { 1 : "a", 2 : "c" }
```

## The twist

I frequently work with object hashes whose values are one-dimensional arrays (vectors). I've written a function using lodash/underscore (NB. only tested with lodash) that performs an array-aware `invert`, whose output object has *keys* that are the unique elements of the input object's value vectors, and *values* that are the input object's keys.

```
function arrayAwareInvert(obj) {
    return _.object(_.flatten(_.map(obj, function(valVec, key) {
        return valVec.map(function(val) { return [ val, key ]; });
    })));
}
```

I'd appreciate feedback on this function.

(NB. I can't use lodash/underscore's built-in `invert` with an object hash with array-valued keys because the resulting object has keys which simply stringify the arrays—an output object key might be `[1, 2, 3].toString()`, and entirely useless.)

## Example use

Just to confirm that it works:

```
arrayAwareInvert({a: [1, 2], b: [3, 4]})
// { 1: "a", 2: "a", 3: "b", 4: "b" }
```

Per the original `invert`'s behavior, if the elements of the input object's value vectors aren't unique (that is, if multiple value vectors contain the same element), the output object's value for those non-unique elements will be one of the input object keys:

```
arrayAwareInvert({a: [1, 2], b: [3, 4, 2]})
// { 1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "b", 4: "b" } // NB: 2: "b" here
```

## Implementation notes

My implementation seems as brute-force as possible: it's effectively a doubly-nested loop, with the outer loop going over all input object keys and the inner loop going over the contents of each input object value (which is a vector).

A `[key, value]` tuple is built for each iteration of the inner-most loop, where "key"/"value" refer to the output object.

[`flatten`](https://lodash.com/docs#flatten) is used to remove one level of nesting, i.e., transform `[[[k1, v1]], [[k2, v2], [k3, v3]]]` to `[[k1, v1], [k2, v2], [k3, v3]]`.

Finally [`object`](https://lodash.com/docs#object) is called to convert this list of 2-tuple key-value pairs into an object hash.

## Summary

Are there implementations that occupy more advantageous positions in the clarity-speed-elegance phase space?

Does this operation have a more general name?

## Analyses of solutions

### `reduce`

I can simplify? @Flambino's [solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/85016/57103) a bit with `_.merge`:

```
function arrayAwareInvert(obj) {
  return _.reduce(obj, function (result, values, key) {
    return _.merge(result, 
                   _.mapValues(_.object(values), function(v) { return key; }));
  }, {});
}
```

I like using `merge` here because it describes what's happening very well. But I don't really like how much code is needed to combine a vector and a string into an object hash with keys as elements of the vector and values as the string:

```
_.mapValues(_.object(values), function(v) { return key; })
```

As one (of many) alternatives, you could do this instead:

```
_.object(values, values.map(function(v) { return key; }))
```

but both of these seem obfuscated, compared with how clear the `reduce` and `merge` steps are.

Comment: Could you clarify why you tagged this question with both [tag:underscore.js] and [tag:lodash.js]?

Comment: [Object keys in JavaScript are _always_ stringified.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6067160/1157100)

Comment: @200_success I added a link to underscore's `invert` to attempt to answer your question. In more general terms, both libraries offer `invert` without a straightforward way to generalize them to array-valued objects, so I tagged them both. Since my implementation uses functions available in both, I feel this is ok.

Comment: @200_success regarding stringified keys: edited to expand on why stringified arrays as keys is different than what I want, and what my function accomplishes.

Comment: Please don't update your question with new/different code, but feel free to ask a new question with the new code. Please see this meta post: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lodash and underscore both have a [`reduce`](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce) (aka "fold") function that works on objects, meaning you could also do this:

```
function arrayAwareInvert(obj) {
  return _.reduce(obj, function (result, values, key) {
    _.forEach(values, function (value) { result[value] = key; });
    return result;
  }, {});
}
```

It's pretty much the functional-style equivalent of Bergi's answer.

Point is, reduce is probably what you want for this.

---

Edit: As Bergi points out in the comments the inner iteration could also be a reduce operation

```
function arrayAwareInvert(obj) {
  return _.reduce(obj, function (result, values, key) {
    return _.reduce(values, function (result, value) {
      result[value] = key;
      return result;
    }, result);
  }, {});
}
```

Comment: Hm, `forEach` is not very functional-style. You'd rather nest two `reduce`s.

Comment: Ah, definitely reduce is the perfect thing for this situation. I was hoping there might be some fancy thing I could do with `partial` or `curry` but I'll take `reduce`. Agree with @Bergi about `forEach` but I will see if that can be replaced with `merge`.

Comment: @Bergi True, but I didn't want to overdo it. This keeps it closer to your solution, which straight-forward to grasp. Still, you're right, and I'll add the reduce-reduce solution

Comment: It's just I'd either do a `for`-`for`, `foreach`-`foreach` or `reduce`-`reduce` solution, but not mix them. Having two loops that essentially do the same written in different ways is confusing.

Comment: @Bergi Sure, I see what you mean. My rationale was partly the an inner reduce requires you to pass in the `result` even though it's already available as a closure, so that seemed a little unnecessary. Sure it's mixing things a little, but with the closure, the `forEach` really ends up doing the same thing as a `reduce`. Anyway, added a reduce-reduce solution

Comment: You can replace the inner loop with something like this: `return _.merge(result, _.mapValues(_.object(values), function(v) {return key;}));`. Will add edit.

Comment: `result[value] = key` not accepted in a FP implementation ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation is quite elegant, but it constructs a lot of intermediate objects so speed could be optimised by writing a more native version:

```
function arrayAwareInvert(obj) {
    var res = {};
    for (var p in obj) {
        var arr = obj[p], l = arr.length;
        for (var i=0; i<l; i++) {
            res[arr[i]] = p;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Which of these is clearer would depend on the readers familiarity with functional programming and the underscore library.

Comment: +1 though you might consider adding a `if(!ob.hasOwnProperty(p)) continue;` line

Comment: @Flambino: It's a data object, not an instance, so it won't have inherited enumerable properties (from `Object.prototype`). No need for `if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, p))`.

Comment: I'm not saying is necessary, but it might be a worthwhile precaution. Besides, lodash uses it, which means your code acts slightly different than the original code. Yes, edge case, but still

Comment: You know, I wrote pretty much this when I needed a non-unique-value-entries version of `arrayAwareInvert` which output an object whose values were arrays, similar to `invert` with the optional second boolean as `true`.

Comment: @AhmedFasih: Yeah, you'd pretty much just do `(res[arr[i]] || res[arr[i]]=[]).push(p);` in the innermost loop instead.

Comment: @Bergi I liked that use of short-circuiting to get at the value of an object or some default `(obj.key || obj.key = []).push(newValue)` but in both Node and Firefox, I get an 'invalid left-hand side assignment' error! (I'm using `obj` and `key` to simplify the example.) `(obj.key = []).push(newValue)` works, so why not `(obj.key || obj.key = []).push`?

Comment: Oops, because `||` binds stronger than `=`. It needs to be `(… || (…=…)).…`